# Recursive type parameters for an almost-cyclic type bound

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have the following two interfaces:

```
/**
 * A marker interface to denote that an object implements a view on some other object.
 *
 * @param <T>   The type of object that is viewed
 */
public interface View<T extends Viewable<View<T>>> {

}
```

---

```
/**
 * An interface for objects that are viewable via a view.
 * 
 * @param <T>   The type of viewable object
 */
public interface Viewable<T extends View<?>> {
    public void addViewCallback(final T view);

    public void removeViewCallback(final T view);
}
```

I want to enforce the following:

- The type parameter of the `View` (called (a)), should be a `Viewable` that views upon that view (a).
- The type parameter of `Viewable` (called (b)), should be a `View`, which is viewable via that same viewable (b).

I think I got the bounds done for `View`, but how am I going to make them work for `Viewable`? What I got now compiles, but does not offer enough protection.

I cannot, as of now, formulate something that gets accepted which I do not want, I can however formulate what I *do* want, if that helps:

- `public class Hand implements Viewable<HandView>`
- `public interface HandView extends View<Hand>`

Comment: Could you formulate an instantiation currently allowed that you don't want to allow?

Comment: @Joffrey Unfortunately no, but I have formulated what I want to have working though, I am worried that `Deck implements Viewable<FieldView>`, where `Deck` and `Field` are *not* related, would be possible.

Comment: I see. The current interfaces' definitions are too restricted to allow what you want, but you don't manage to broaden them without allowing `Deck implements Viewable<FieldView>`, is that your problem?

Comment: *A marker interface to denote that an object implements a view on some other object.* It doesn't seem to be *some other object* but the object itself. That's what bugs me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the use case itself? It seems that, as @SimonAndréForsberg pointed out, you might not need that much complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed with @SimonAndréForsberg, programming too defensively is often an unnecessary waste of time, and we should trust our own declarations.

However, for the fun of it, here is a solution to enforce all the restrictions you want on class/interfaces declarations at compile time.

### Declarations

#### The `View` interface:

```
public interface View<T extends Viewable<T, ?>> {}
```

- Here, we just want to ensure that the type parameter is a `Viewable`.
- The second type argument does not need restriction, because the declaration of `Viewable` would not allow a `Viewable<T,?>` to exist if the `?` were not itself a `View<T>`.

#### The `Viewable` interface:

```
public interface Viewable<T extends Viewable<T,?>, V extends View<T>> {
    public void addViewCallback(final V view);
    public void removeViewCallback(final V view);
}
```

- Here, `T` needs to be declared as a `Viewable` because we use it as type parameter for `View<T>` at the end of the line.
- Same as before, no restriction needed on `?` because we say right after that the second type parameter needs to be a `View<T>` if the first type parameter is a `T`.

### Usage

```
public class Hand implements Viewable<Hand, HandView> {
    @Override
    public void addViewCallback(HandView view) {}

    @Override
    public void removeViewCallback(HandView view) {}

}

public interface HandView extends View<Hand> {
}
```

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Thanks! Yeah, that was painful ^^

Answer (score 7):

As your `View` is a *marker interface*, and the fact that you as of now haven't formulated anything that gets accepted which you *don't* want, I question the use of the `View` interface entirely. You're putting an unnecessary restriction on yourself that leads to nothing but trouble.

## Simplify!

```
/**
 * An interface for objects that are viewable via a view.
 * 
 * @param <T>   The type of viewable object
 */
public interface Viewable<T> {
    public void addViewCallback(final T view);

    public void removeViewCallback(final T view);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the simplification suggestion. However, I think it is simplified too much here, since the OP wants some restriction on the type passed to the methods.

Comment: @Joffrey I think the OP is putting to many restrictions on himself. I see no need to restrict this at all. It's up to implementations of the interface to pick the type that they choose.

Comment: Very true, programming too defensively is sometimes an unnecessary waste of time. The OP should probably trust his own classes delcarations :)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working, while taking all other answers here into consideration.

It seems like [@Joffrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365057/2057294) got me started quite a bit, but then I realised that it is simply not possible this way, as method arguments cannot be *covariant*.

I also agree that it might be too much work, but that's why it is some experimental stuff, at work with time pressure I might indeed think twice before wasting time on this.

One of the possible solutions is:

```
/**
 * A marker interface to denote that an object implements a view on some other object.
 *
 * @param <T>   The type of object that is viewed
 */
public interface View<T extends Viewable<T, ? extends View<T>>> {

}
```

---

```
/**
 * An interface for objects that are viewable via a view.
 * 
 * @param <T>   The type of viewable object
 * @param <V>   The concrete view on the viewable object
 */
public interface Viewable<T extends Viewable<T, V>, V extends View<T>> {
    public void addViewCallback(final V view);

    public void removeViewCallback(final V view);
}
```

Example implementation:

```
public interface HandView extends View<Hand> {
    public void onCardAdded(final Card card);

    public void onCardPlayed(final int cardIndex);

    public void onCardsSwapped(final int cardIndexOne, final int cardIndexTwo);
}
```

---

```
public class Hand extends AbstractCollection<Card> implements Collection<Card>, Viewable<Hand, HandView> {
    private final List<HandView> views = new ArrayList<>();

    //...

    @Override
    public void addViewCallback(final HandView view) {
        views.add(Objects.requireNonNull(view));
    }

    @Override
    public void removeViewCallback(final HandView view) {
        views.remove(Objects.requireNonNull(view));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(final Card card) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(card);
        States.requireFalse(isFull(), "hand is full");
        list.add(card);
        views.forEach(view -> view.onCardAdded(card));
        return true;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the extra restriction on the ? for the delcaration of the `View` interface. Indeed, the `Viewable` declaration already limits the second type argument.

Answer (score 2):

The only way this has ever worked for me was to specify both View and Viewable type parameters:

- `public interface View<VB extends Viewable<VB,T>, T extends View<VB,T>>`
- `public interface Viewable<VB extends Viewable<VB,T>, T extends View<VB,T>>`

Keep in mind that this will require you to create specific interfaces:

- `public interface Hand implements Viewable<Hand,HandView>`
- `public interface HandView extends View<Hand,HandView>`

Comment: You might be on to something here, but this does not compile at the moment, which makes it hard to know what you're on to. `Incorrect number of arguments for type Viewable; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <View<T>>` (Error x2)

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't compile, `Incorrect number of arguments for type View; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <T>` here: `VB extends Viewable<**View<T>**>`

Comment: Gah, that's what happens when I try to write code without an IDE... refixed(2).

Comment: @TassosBassoukos So hard without IDE indeed ^^ Especially for all these interlaced generics!